# Can you use html entities in links?

Tags: html

The following link contains an HTML entity (`&amp;`). Is this okay in all browsers?

```
<a href="/somepage/1?tab=category&amp;category_id=2">Category 2</a>
```

Comment: You should not do that. URLs should be encoded using "percent encoding". Certainly the above URL is valid. But that does not mean it expresses what you expect :-)

Comment: Why do you need it? Why not use just `&`?

Comment: jquery.attr('href','...') will html entity encode it

Comment: @nicael: Because `&` has special meaning in HTML.

Comment: @arkascha: Why would the OP expect a query string like `tab=category%26category_id=2` with a percent-encoded ampersand and not something like `tab=category&category_id=2`?

Comment: @BoltClock I did not say so. But since the OP posted an otherwise non escaped path in the anchor tag we have to assume the tag gets used normally. In such case there is absolutely no sense in doing anything to the ampersand _if_ the OP wanted to express what you expect. So obviously something different must be the OP's goal. Using a notation like an html entity suggests that the OP want to express the literal character.

Comment: @Bolt And it looks like this special meaning is exactly the thing OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> <a href="...&amp;...">
> ```

Yes, this is *the*<sup>1</sup> correct way to encode an ampersand in an HTML attribute. This is unrelated to the fact that the attribute contains a URL.

There are cases where you don't strictly need to escape the ampersand, but  the simplest and perhaps most reliable option is to always encode it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, you can also use `&#38;` or `&#x26;`, but `&amp;` is the most idiomatic.